# How Sri Ramanujacharya interpret Aham Brahmasmi?

Tags: brihadaranyaka-upanishad

I have come across the interpretation of Sri Madhvacharya on Aham Brahmasmi. But I would like to know the Sri Ramanuja's interpretations.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! If you are familiar with Tamizh, you can listen to U. Ve. Sri Velukkudi Krishnan Swamy's Upanyaasams on Brihadaranyaka Upanishad (available on YouTube) for explanations based on Sri RamanujAcharya Sampradayam.

Comment: **Relevant**: While the question is rightly marked *possible duplicate*, I just want to point out that for the question posed here, valid answer is absent in the linked question. Just a FYI for those interested.